# Flag columns, Varchar or INT?

Tags: php, mysql

I often use (what I call) 'flag' columns in my DBs, such as the following:

```
Column 'Type':
0 = CREATOR
1 = OPERATIVE
2 = APPROVER
```

But is this the right way to do this? I only ask because it might be confusing coming back to it later when I don't remember what zero, one, two, or three mean.  Wouldn't it be better to simple mark them as `CREATOR` etc?

What is the general accepted practice for this?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

A flag is typically a boolean `true` and `false` or `0` and `1` expressed in a `bit` (MySQL 5.0.3+), or `tinyint`. If you have more than 2 possible values, those values could be stored in an `ENUM` within MySQL, otherwise, those possible values should be stored in their own table and referenced using a foreign key relationship (normalization).

Answer (score 1):

**INTEGERS are favored over STRING in terms of indexing.**

But you could have another table that only stores the `roles` with a `INT role_id primary key` and `UNIQUE VARCHAR role column`. And then, in your `user_roles`, have `user_id` and `role_id` as a `FOREIGN KEY` pointing to the `` roles`.`role_id ``.

- This way the role stays `INT` but can be `JOINED` to the `roles` table to get its name.
- And when you need to use a `role` literal, you query the `role_id` from the `roles` table.

**It's normalization.**

**PS**: *But it might be overkill depending on your user base.* You might get away easier with `indexed VARCHAR role columns`.

Comment: creating another table? It just seems silly to create another table just to remember what a value is, when the PHP will know instinctively.

Comment: @Chud37 It allows you to scale without hardcoding values in your script. It's not silly at all... for large sites.

Comment: @Chud37 *"instinctively"*? Since when does PHP code has instincts?

Comment: @Chud37 It's not silly at all if you understand normalization principles.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question might be "enumerated types", which are described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html).  These allow you to associate a string with a numeric value as a type in MySQL -- a practice common in "real" programming languages.

Often, however, you don't want to do that because you specifically want a reference table for the object.  Generally a name is an "entity" in relational terms.  This suggests having a table:

```
create table OperatorType (
    OperatorTypeId int auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255)
)
```

In this case, all references will be to the id in the table, which would be an integer.

Using an id without an enumerated type or reference table should be discouraged.  Presumably, the purpose of the `name` is to have human readable output.  You do not want different queries (and query writers) inventing their own names for the operator types.  Instead, use the built-in database mechanisms to handle this situation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `int` / `tinyint`. And always use `comments` which will help you to remember whats all values are.

Numeric values are better in shorting and comparision.

Enum can be a option. But common problem with enum values are if your flags are increasing then its little bit tough to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use VARCHAR.  VARCHAR is only efficient for strings over size 3.

[Varchar Mysql Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

In this case you could use CHAR(1) and use the values of C, O, and A as a tickler.

Another way to remove the remembrance of the code is to define library functions that tell you what it is such as:

```
function isCreator($value) {
  if($value === 0) return true;
}
```

Good question.

Answer (score 0):

I always use tinyint. It takes up less space than a varchar and is much better for speed and indexing. I know many who use enum and although I like the idea I prefer the flexibility of tinyint. Field comments are also a great tool that can be very helpful down the road.

Except for the cases where I know I'm storing a binary yes/no value I always use values above zero. This can save much confusion in the long run since PHP evaluates zero and false identically (a big concern of you gathering value from a web form).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use int as datatype for the column "type"
As for your worry about forgetting later in the long run what 0,1,2 repersents you can always provide the description as table column comments

you alter the field and add comment to it by executing the following alter query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `Type` `Type` INT( 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 is CREATOR, 1 is OPERATIVE,2 is APPROVER'
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: **`INT(2)` does not affect size but only formatting :)** `TINYINT` is the small data-type you are looking for aka `char` in `C`. It's `TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `MEDIUMINT`, `INT`, `BIGINT`.

Comment: yes but I believe the question here asked that how will he able to remember that what 0,1,2 denotes in the long run hence the alter query to add the comment to table field as for using INT(2) was just to show the alter query for adding the comment and ofcourse if he want to change the INT to TINYINT to change the size that is also a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
make your type column a enum field and set the value like '0','1','2'
```

and in the comment field write as 0 = CREATOR , 1 = OPERATIVE , 2 = APPROVER.It will help you to remember the values,when you will look at your database a year after.

Comment: Why? The point of `enum` is that you can give proper names to the different valid values. Giving numeric string names to enums is really bad, if you pass it as number sometimes and otherwise as string. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR` is the worst type to use in this scenario, as others mentioned You may consider `ENUM`, `INT` or relation table with roles.

Differences are:

When using `ENUM` for inserting records You can use literals and numbers as values.
When selecting again You can use both literals and numbers in `WHERE` but returned values will be a strings, if You would like to get numbers You have to select `columnsname+0` in fields list.

When using `INT` You can use only numbers.

So it sounds like `ENUM` should be better plus if You create some static constants to hold numeric values in Your code everything will get just easier.

Now is relation better than `ENUM`?

If You require flexibility and would like to add new roles from PA relation table is the only solution You should consider.

If Your roles are constant and will never change `ENUM` is better without need of involving JOINs.